# Adding Custom Objects in Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, cocoa, view, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I'm working with Objective-C and Xcode for about a year. I customise a lot of generic objects. Few days ago one of my friend asked me a question, but I couldn't answer him. So I try to do something my self. 
**For example:**
*I created this Custom View:*
[image]

How can I add this View to the **Object Library**?. Here:
[image]

I don't really know why do I need this. But I decide to figure out how to do this. I hope you could help me with this.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I don't think this will work. You are putting buttons on "top" of a custom view placeholder. The custom view placeholder is used to be able to use - yeah you guessed right - custom user defined views. So of which class would your view-with-5-buttons-on-top be? I think you are running into a dead end, because that's just not the way to do it in Xcode. If you want to design your custom view graphically, just create a NIB file for it.

Comment: @guitarflow it is just an example. But how you can place it in this object library. I never used it. And I don't think that I would. But I would like to know.

Comment: I don't think that you can add your own view objects into the object library. Everything I know of are user-defined code snippets which will show up on the right.

Comment: @guitarflow Exactly. That what I told him(my friend). So that is right. Thank you!

Comment: Posted the above comments as an answer. Would love to see an upvote and if you would mark it as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will work. You are putting buttons on "top" of a custom view placeholder. The custom view placeholder is used to be able to use - yeah you guessed right - custom user defined views.

So of which class would your view-with-5-buttons-on-top be? I think you are running into a dead end, because that's just not the way to do it in Xcode. If you want to design your custom view graphically, just create a NIB file for it.

I don't think that you can add your own view objects into the object library. Everything I know of are user-defined code snippets which will show up on the right.

---

**Edit**

There were things called IB plugins in Interface Builder and Xcode versions prior to 4.
Those were discontinued in Xcode 4 as can be read here for example :
http://xcodebook.com/2011/03/no-interface-builder-plugin-support-in-xcode-4/

Further searches for IB plugin gives a lot more guys telling the same.

Best,

Flo

Comment: Downrated because a) you didn't answer the question and b) you indicated that you didn't know how to use the "Custom Objects" and c) I need to know the answer as well... not solved.

Comment: @FeloneousCat : I just edited my answer. a) The original poster thought the answer was helpful. b) I`m pretty sure I do know how to use them  c) How will it help if you give me a downvote then? Just because I didn`t answer it the way you wanted to?

Comment: The question was "How can I add this View to the Object Library?" - if you indicated how to add anything to it, then I must have missed it.

What it indicated is you don't know how to use the Object Library. Neither does the OP. So, I have to wonder, how do you think you answered the question?

Comment: Honestly, if you spent some time googling instead of telling me what I don't seem to know in your opinion, you would've had an answer days ago. This is a helping site and I at least tried to help. Would it have been better if you found the question with not even a hint? No offense, but this is pretty lame. I hope you are at least satisfied by my updated answer. ( by the way : didn't even take 5 minutes of Googling. And that although I don't even know how to use the object library!! ;) )